# Convert a column of a table to vector

Tags: matlab

I have a table named cellName of size 10000*1. Each entry is a character string of cell names. Each cell name is of different length.
And I want to coerce it into a vector with 10000 elements. How can i do that in matlab? It should be very easy as that in r but i didn't find such command in matlab.

OR: I used readtable to load the 10000*1 table from csv file at the very beginning. It would be great if I can directly read the 10000*1 entries as a single vector too. This is what i did at first.

```
cellName = readtable('cell.csv');
cellName=cellName(1:10000,1);
```

Thank you in advance!

Clear example: A is a table of 5*1. 
A= apple
   banana
   pear
   peach
   watermelon

And i want to coerce A into a vector of 5 elements: A=[apple,banana,pear,peach,watermelon] instead of a table

Comment: Please provide clear example of what you want

Comment: @saeedmasoomi edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a character cell array is what you want, I may have your answer. I also suggest you to read how to [access data in a table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html).

`readtable` returns a Matlab `table` data type when succeeded. The `table` can be accessed like `struct` with your column name as the fieldname, or be indexed by `{}` operator like you would access a cell array.

In your example, assuming A is the return value of `readtable` and your

```
A = table({'apple','banana','pear','peach','watermelon'}','variableNames',{'cellName'})
```

Then you can either call

```
cellName = A.cellName
```

or

```
cellName = A{:,1}
```

to get your cell array.

Comment: But i want a vector instead of a cell array. i tried cell2mat(cellName) and it doesn't work. Any idea to get a vector instead?

Comment: Character string with various length cannot be stored in a regular numerical vector. They have to be stored in a cell data type and you access it like a regular vector with cell access operator `{}`. BTW, Nx1 cell is a vector in Matlab. You can test with isvector(cellName) in my example.

Comment: s1 = {'Thanks' 'so' 'much' 'Chang'};
s2 = {'you' 'are' 'correct.' };

s3 = {s1{:},s2{:}}